# In Mulesoft how to stop SFTP connector to read file when ActiveMQ is trying to reconnect

Tags: mulesoft

I have a reliable acquisition flow where an inbound SFTP connector is polling and reading the file and publishing to JMS ActiveMq. I have an issue when ActiveMQ is down. JMS connector get in to reconnection mode lets say every minute but SFTP is actively reading the files and try to publish the file in ActiveMq. which causes the loss of message and the concept of deadletter queue also does not work as JMS is down.

Is there a way we can stop reading the file until the JMS successfully reconnect?  also what if the message was in flight and JMS get down before message end up in the queue? will the message rollback?

I am using Mule 3.9

Answer (score 0):

If you set the flow processing strategy to synchronous and use only 1 receiver thread in the connector configuration. Then it should not try to read a new file if the previous one wasn't processed. Without those changes it is not a correct implementation of the reliable pattern.

More information:

- Documentation of reliable patterns: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/reliability-patterns.
- KB Article: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-fetch-files-in-order-using-the-FTP-connector

Example:

```
<sftp:connector name="sftpConn">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1" />
</sftp:connector>

<flow name="mainFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    ...
```